# Anyone can explain how does these shell script work?

Tags: bash, shell

```
    ckFile() {
  if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
    err "$2 File '$1' not found";
  fi
}

    ckFileSz() {
  ckFile $1 $2;
  SZ=`ls -l $1 | awk '{print $5}'`;
  if [ "$SZ" == "0" ]; then
    err "$2 file '$1' is zero length";
  fi
}
```

Comment: These are 2 shell function definitions. What specifically is confusing you?

Comment: just a silly question i am not sure what ! symbol means in this " ! -e "$1" " and why the ckFile $1 $2 has two argument

Comment: `ckFileSz()` would be better written `ckFileSz() { if test -s "$1"; then err "$2 file '$1' has size zero"; fi; }`  There is no need to pipe ls to awk simply to check if a file has size zero.

Comment: Check out [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` is the first argument passed to the [[ function ]](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html). For example  if you call the function like  :

```
ckFile /path/to/somefile
```

`/path/to/somefile` would become the first argument(ie `$1`).

The `[]` is the alternative form of the bash [[ test ]](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html). In short with

```
if [ ! -e "$1" ]
```

You are checking if the file `$1` does not (`!` negates a condition) exists (`-e` option)  on the system.

> and why the `ckFile $1 $2` has two argument

Little information is known about the second argument here. You may update the question with how the function is called.